# Have a Go function accept different structs as input with methods

Tags: unit-testing, go, types, mocking, assertions

I'm rather new to Go and I can't seem to wrap my head around it's struct/interface system while trying to create a mock object for an AWS s3manager uploader's unit testing.

In my package file I have:

```
package uploader

import (
        "fmt"
        "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
        "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
        "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager"
        "os"
)

func GetS3Uploader() *s3manager.Uploader {
    conf := aws.Config{Region: aws.String("eu-west-1")}
    sess := session.New(&conf)
    uploader := s3manager.NewUploader(sess)
    return uploader
}

func uploadFile(uploader interface{}) {

    uploader.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{
       Bucket: aws.String("A"),
       Key:    aws.String("B"),
       Body:   bytes.NewReader([]byte("C")),
    })

}
```

and in the matching uploader_test.go there is the following code, containing the mock objects:

```
package uploader_test

import (
    . "github.com/onsi/ginkgo"
    . "github.com/something/reponame/uploader"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager"
)

type mockUploadOutput struct {
    Location  string
    VersionID *string
    UploadID  string
}

type mockUploader struct {
}

func (*mockUploader) Upload(input *s3manager.UploadInput) (mockUploadOutput, error) {
    versionID := "TESTVERSION"
    mockUploadResponse := mockUploadOutput{
        Location:  "TESTLOCATION",
        VersionID: &versionID,
        UploadID:  "TESTUPLOADID",
    }
    return mockUploadResponse, nil
}

var _ = Describe("Reportuploader", func() {

    var (
        mockUp mockUploader
    )

    Describe("Upload()", func() {
        Context("With mocked uploader object", func() {
            It("should return the predefined mockUploadResponse", func() {

                uploadFile(mockUp)

            })
        })
    })
})
```

But when I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
uploader.Upload undefined (type interface {} is interface with no methods)
```

My aim is to have the uploadFile function accept both the *s3manager.Uploader object and the mocked mockUploader as valid arguments, and recognize both their Upload methods. I tried asserting the type before calling the Upload method, but that only gave a different error. Can anyone help, and tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the type signature to `func uploadFile(uploader interface{}) {`, which means it accepts anything as an argument, but you cannot call any method on `uploader`, because your type signature `interface{}` does not any methods on it.

It looks like what you want to do is:

```
type Uploader interface {
    Upload(input *s3manager.UploadInput) 
}

func uploadFile(uploader Uploader) {
    uploader.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{
        Bucket: aws.String("A"),
        Key:    aws.String("B"),
        Body:   bytes.NewReader([]byte("C")),
    })
}
```

But you are going to need to match the function signature, and it looks like one of them has:

```
(mockUploadOutput, error)
```

and the other a

```
(*s3manager.UploadOutput, error)
```

so, what I would probably do is just return a real `(*s3manager.UploadOutput, error)` from your mock:

```
func (*mockUploader) Upload(input *s3manager.UploadInput) (*s3manager.UploadOutput, error) {
  versionID := "TESTVERSION"
  mockUploadResponse := &s3manager.UploadOutput{
      Location:  "TESTLOCATION",
      VersionID: &versionID,
      UploadID:  "TESTUPLOADID",
  }
  return mockUploadResponse, nil
}
```

Comment: This helps a lot in understanding what I was missing but now I seem to be getting another error:
`runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference` with the stack trace pointing to the line where this starts:
`uploader.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{`

Comment: Okay, I got it to work by removing the asterisk in front of mockUploader, in `func (*mockUploader) Upload(input *s3manager.UploadInput)` and taking @peter 's advice and putting the full argument list in there with the `options ...func(*s3manager.Uploader)` part.

Answer (score 1):

You have to give both types a common set if methods. Common means the name, argument types, and return types must be identical. Since you can't change the real implementation, your only option is to have the mock mimic the s3 type. s3's Upload method is defined as follows:

```
Upload(input *s3manager.UploadInput, options ...func(*s3manager.Uploader)) (*s3manager.UploadOutput, error)
```

Your mock must have the exact same method:

```
func (*mockUploader) Upload(input *s3manager.UploadInput, options ...func(*s3manager.Uploader)) (*s3manager.UploadOutput, error) {
    // Implementation
}
```

Note that you cannot change the return types.

Now both types share an interface that you can depend on:

```
type Uploader interface {
    Upload(input *s3manager.UploadInput, options ...func(*s3manager.Uploader)) (*s3manager.UploadOutput, error)
}

func uploadFile(uploader Uploader) {
}
```